# how can i apply jquery elastic on multiple textareas

Tags: php, jquery

i am generating multiple textareas with php with id i.e

```
<textarea id="here php generated id" class="txta">
```

now i want to apply jquery elastic to each of these textareas...

Comment: use class instead of id as selector in jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$('textarea.txta').elastic();

it'll apply to all textareas having class txta...